# Simple form submit button not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, submit, simple-form

somehow my form is not working and I dont know why. Heres my code:

```
<%= simple_form_for @cr, url: edit_cr_path do |f| %>

<hr>
Design Office Involvements<br>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :design_office_ids, DesignOffice.all, :id, :sub, {:item_wrapper_class => 'checkbox_container'} %>
<hr>
Procurement Involvements<br>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :procurement_ids, Procurement.all, :id, :sub, {:item_wrapper_class => 'checkbox_container'} %>
<hr>
Installation Involvements<br>
    <%= f.collection_check_boxes :installation_ids, Installation.all, :id, :sub, {:item_wrapper_class => 'checkbox_container'} %>
<hr>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">  
        Assessment Status
        <%= f.input :assessment_status, :collection => [['Impacted','Impacted'],['Not impacted','Not impacted'],['Under assessment','Under assessment'],['New','New']], label: false, selected: ['New', 'New'] %>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div style="float: right">
            <%= f.button :submit, 'Save' %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>

<% end %>
```

Controller methods looking like this:

```
class CrsController < ApplicationController

    def edit
        @cr = Cr.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @cr = Cr.find(params[:id])
        @cr.update_attributes(cr_params)
        redirect_to edit_cr_path(@cr)
    end

    private

    def cr_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:id, :assessment_status)
    end

end
```

And routes like this:

```
EndToEndManagement::Application.routes.draw do

  get '/cr/:id', :to => 'crs#edit', :as => 'edit_cr'
  put '/cr/:id', :to => 'crs#update'
  patch '/cr/:id', :to => 'crs#update'

end
```

And thats the html code rails makes of my submit button:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div style="float: right">
        <input class="btn" name="commit" type="submit" value="Save" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I think the submit button is not correctly attached to the form but I tried to move it and clear some divs but nothing worked.

Best regards.

EDIT:

Thats what I tested

1. Removed my routes in routes.rb and replaced it with `resources :crs` and changed my first line in the form to `<%= simple_form_for @cr do |f| %>`. Didnt work!
2. Changed my simple_form to normal form. Didnt work!
3. Wrote a whole testapp with a scaffold and this form an it worked but I dont know why so I added part by part to my actual app and nothing made it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my mistake! Not that it would be so mind blowing but I will still post it :D

Had this small mistake in my application.html.erb

```
<div style="font-size: 1.3em"
   <%= yield %>
</div>
```

Changed it to:

```
<div style="font-size: 1.3em">
   <%= yield %>
</div>
```

And now it works fine.

Comment: The first line in the top example is missing the ending arrow-bracket (...font-size: 1.3 em"**>**).

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem as **edit_cr_path** is the right url to go when you're trying to save a form.
You'll need another route:

```
post '/crs', :to => 'crs#create'
```

In your view, you probably won't need the url option as Rails can infer just looking at the object.

```
<%= simple_form_for @cr do |f| %>
```

But your object needs to be a new instance coming from your controller:

```
class CrsController < ApplicationController

    def new
      @cr = Cr.new #or whatever else to initialize the object
    end

    def create
      #save the instance here
    end
```

Comment: Thanks but thats not working and creates exactly the same html.

Comment: No problem. That was a fix for your submit button. Now what else is happening? Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: As far as I know the code for my submit button should work with simple_form. Nevertheless I dont really know what to look for cause I cant really see any problems here. Not sure if in the html is not missing <div class="form-action">? Could that be the problem?

Comment: Cant imagine that it has something to do with the routing since rails would give me huge routing error. I rather think that it has something to do with the html convertion. Tried to use the same methods in a default scaffold and its not working.

Comment: A routing error is not happening because you are routing to a valid path. It's just that this path is the edit action, which calls your edit page again. That's why you always have the same exact html.